# velocity vs. speed

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's more appropriate for the following context? 
Someone jumped from a building (3rd floor for example) then I want to ask how fast he fell in terms of Km per hour. For this purpose is there a difference between the following two choices?

> What's the **velocity** of a person falling freely from 3rd floor?
>
> What's the **speed** of a person falling freely from 3rd floor?

Or maybe both aren't understandable enough for my purpose?